# Change battery side side-light bulb 2004 VW Polo E RHD

Tags: vw, polo

I am trying to change the passenger side-light bulb on my right-hand-drive VW Polo, without removing the air filter and the entire battery case.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

- Remove the battery

  - (remove negative terminal first)
- Remove the battery case side-walls

  - There's a trick to this (see below)
  - Split the 2 positive cables
- Remove the main beam wires & bulb
- Replace the side-light bulb
- Refitting is a reversal of removal

**Remove the battery**

1. Pop the battery cover/fuse box off the top of the battery
2. Remove the negative terminal
3. This is a good point to split the positive leads before un-clamping the positive electrode:

[image: Positive battery terminal]

4. Unbolt the battery brace at the base of the front of the battery

**Remove the battery case side walls**

1. Remove the front panel by pressing the front three catches and prising 5mm forward, and sliding the panel upward:

[image: Battery front side panel]

Note: There are 4 catches on the battery case side walls

[image: Four catches on bottom of the battery case walls]

2. Pop the two rear catches by pulling the rear of the battery case wall slightly downward and toward the front of the car:

[image: Pull the rear of the case]

3. Pop the two side catches by with your fingers down the outer side of the case

[image: Location of side catches]

4. Lift the case side-walls off.

**Remove the main beam wires & bulb**

1. Pull the positive terminal from the main beam bulb.  **Do not touch the glass of the bulb**

[image: Bulb wires]

2. Remove the spring catch securing the main beam bulb in palce
3. Pull the negative terminal from the bulb holder
4. Pull the side-light bulb holder from the reflector assembly

[image: Bulbs removed]

5. Pull the bulb from the bulb holder

More [photos here](https://goo.gl/photos/XbYVaX6DVvdrJDAD6), in case it helps - Note that you don't need to remove the air filter and battery case base if you follow the instructions above.

Comment: Ouch! I would not like a car where something as trivial as changing a light bulb is that complicated.

Comment: If the question was to change the bulb WITHOUT removing the battery and case, how does this answer the question?

Comment: The air filter and battery case base was not removed - only the side panels.  Unfortunately I had to remove the entire battery case (& cut off corroded base  nuts) & air filter base to find this out.